# .NET C# code not picking up SQLite database changes

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I have a .NET C# application which uses a local SQLite database. I can read the database but if I change a value manually in the db by means of an external tool I don't read back the change on the C# code. If I restart the application I can read back the changes

**EDIT**

That's the initialization; mostly .NET magic here

```
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddLogging();
    services.AddOptions();
    services.AddDbContext<ServicesDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlite($"Filename={fileName}", b => b.MigrationsAssembly("ReviewerServices.Data")));
    services.AddTransient<INetworkUtilities, NetworkUtilities>();
```

Usage is even simpler:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<FtpServerGroup>> GetFtpPullListAsync(DateTime baseTime)
{
    var servers = await context.FtpServerGroup
        .Include(r => r.FtpServers)
        .Include(r => r.Instruments)
        .Where(w => !w.Disabled)
        .ToListAsync();

    servers = servers.FindAll(w => baseTime - w.FtpLastPullTime >= w.FtpPullInterval);
    return servers.AsEnumerable();
}
```

Comment: How are you communicating with the DB? There may be some sort of caching engine sitting in front of it

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: I'm doing that... just a sec...

Comment: You are probably using WAL, otherwise you wouldn't be able to use the same database from multiple threads/processes. WAL means that the changes will be applied to the data file *at some point*, which may be several seconds *after* they are made.

Comment: @DanHastings sure, but I would expect the cache to get invalidated if I change something, I mean, ok caching but this one is caching too much!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you, what's WAL?

Comment: not if its something like redis or memcached sitting in front of it? if you are using some sort of library to perform the query rather than directly doing it, there may be some caching measures in place that are unrelated to the db

Comment: WAL = Write Ahead Logging. You can either lock the database file (in which case no-one else can write to the DB) or use WAL. In this case, changes are written to a log and applied to the data files as soon as possible. SQLite is an *embedded* database which means the *processes* themselves have to handle these updates. This takes time.

Comment: I'm going to provide some code...